# foreach invalid argument error

Tags: php

I've been getting an Invalid argument warning for `foreach` and Undefined variable error for number, how could that be fixed? code shown below

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td colspan='6'><h4><small>Online Players</small></h4></td>
    </tr>
    <td>Player Id</td>
    <td>Nickname</td>
    <td>Score</td>
    <td>Ping</td>
   </thead>

    <?php
    foreach($info as $number) //warning line
    {
      echo "<tr><td>".$number['PlayerID']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$number['Nickname']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$number['Score']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$number['Ping']."</td></tr>";
    }
    if($number == 0)
    {
      echo "<tr><td colspan='6'><small>No players online or the database is too busy..</small></td></tr>";
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: `$info` is not an array. that's all.

Comment: You need to show us where you define `$info` before using it in a `foreach ($array as $value)`, or if you haven't defined it previously than that's the problem. It's the declaration of `$info` that is the problem not the code you've posted.

Comment: As mentioned above, $info is no where defined in your code snippet.